# Return of value to shareholders in an ISA

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, shares, isa, capital-gains-tax

**Note I am situated in the UK.**

I hold a number of Vodafone of shares in a stocks and shares ISA. My broker has issued the following message to me:

> Vodafone has confirmed plans to sell its stake in Verizon Wireless to
>   Verizon Communications. As part of the sale, Vodafone intends to
>   return an estimated $84 billion to investors holding Vodafone shares
>   as at the close of business on the 21 February 2014, partly in Verizon
>   shares and partly in cash (the combined value of which is referred to
>   as the ‘Return of Value’).
>
> The exact number of Verizon shares and value of cash to be returned to
>   shareholders is expected to be announced on 19 February 2014 and 21
>   February 2014 respectively. Vodafone also plans to carry out a share
>   consolidation of its ordinary share capital.
>
> The Return of Value can be treated as capital (referred to as the B
>   share option) or an income payment (referred to as the C share option)
>   for UK tax purposes. Investors will receive the same value of cash and
>   number of Verizon shares whether they choose capital or income;
>   however, the tax treatment of the combined value (Verizon shares and
>   cash) will differ.
>
> **The options are designed to allow shareholders to receive the Verizon
>   shares and cash in a way that best suits their own personal tax
>   situation. However, as you hold your Vodafone shares in an ISA there
>   are no capital gains or income tax implications to consider.
>   Therefore, we will automatically elect for you to receive the Return
>   of Value as capital. If you are happy with this option, you do not
>   need to notify us, however you will need to complete a W-8BEN form
>   (see below).**
>
> If you would prefer to receive your Return of Value as an income
>   payment please notify us by noon on Friday 14 February 2014 using the
>   orange Corporate Actions icon alongside your Vodafone shares in your
>   Vantage Stocks & Shares ISA and follow the instructions provided.

First things first what I would like to clear up is that by capital (option B) they mean I will receive Verizon shares... is that the case?

My second piece of confusion (I want to be absolutely certain of this) is with this statement:

> as you hold your Vodafone shares in an ISA **there are no capital gains or income tax implications to consider.**

So even if I opt to receive my return of value as an income payment (option C) I will not be charged either income or capital gains tax on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will receive a combination of Verizon shares and cash whether you chose option B or C.

Option B means that your "Return of Value" will be treated as capital - ie: as a capital gain.

Option C means that your "Return of Value" will be treated as income - ie: as a dividend.

As your ISA has favourable tax status, you don't end up paying any capital gain tax or income tax on dividend income. So it won't matter which option you chose.